# Why might fork() not return to the child?

Tags: c++, linux, fork

My application needs to `fork()`, but sometimes (about 1/10 times) the `fork` doesn't return to the child. The forking section of my code is equivalent to:

```
void myFunc()
{
  pid_t pid = fork();
  if( pid == -1 )
  {
    printf( "Error! %d\n", errno );
    exit(1);
  }
  else if( pid == 0 )
  {
    printf( "In the child\n" );
    _Exit(0);
  }
  else
  {
    printf( "In the parent\n" );
    int status;
    if( waitpid( pid, &status, 0 ) == pid )
    {
      // check status
    }
    printf( "Finished waitpid\n" );
  }
}
```

Although most of the time I see the output:

```
In the parent
In the child
Finished waitpid
```

sometimes I just see

```
In the parent
```

Now, I suspect this could be because we are very memory limited on this platform, so I've overstepped the mark in the parent application, and there isn't enough memory to `fork`. However, in this circumstance I expect the call to `fork()` to return -1, and me to land in the error condition.

Is it possible that I could still be instantaneously running out of memory, but `fork()` not telling me about it?

Comment: The `fork` is succeeding. It may be the `printf` that's failing. Where is the output going? To a terminal or to a file?

Comment: You forgot to call `fflush` before the `fork`  and just after each `printf`

Comment: Good call with the `fflush`, and the printf is's just going to `stdout`.

Comment: I've just added a call to `waitpid` that I'm doing in my code, to show that this never completes.

Comment: Should your title be "...not return to the *parent*" ?

Comment: Doh, sorry, the title is correct, but I've typed the output wrong. Fixed.

Comment: Are there any other threads in the parent?

Comment: Yeah, there's quite a lot going on in there parent actually: the parent was originally forked as it's a daemon process, and there are a handful of pthreads.

Comment: Since you call `_Exit` not `exit` after the `printf` no automatic flushing happens. You need to call manually `fflush`...

Comment: I understand why you would need to `fflush` before forking, so that the child inherits an empty buffer, but I'm not sure why you would need to `fflush` before `_Exit`ing from the child?

Comment: `fflush` shouldn't be necessary because you are using '\n' at the end of the string which should flush  the buffer.

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly what I was thinking.

Comment: I just test your function about a 1M times with `( while [ $(./test | wc -l) = "2" ]; do printf "."; done ) && echo "Wooooo"` and  everything was working properly. Maybe your program is doing something that it shouldn't.